# Cómo solucionar “Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()”

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo problemas para conectar mi aplicación PHP a mi base de datos.

Cada vez que actualizo la página aparece el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in 
C:\user\htdocs\gestor\db\connect.php:9 Stack trace: #0 
C:\user\htdocs\gestor\utility.php(10): include() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\user\htdocs\gestor\db\connect.php on line 9
```

Este es el código que utilizo para conectarme:

```
<?php

    $serverName = "gestorSQL";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBGestor", "UID"=>"gestor.user", "PWD"=>"gestorpass1");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( !$conn ) {
        echo "The connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

?>
```

Esta es información adicional que puede ayudar a solucionar el problema.

- **Versión de PHP:** 7.3.27
- **MS SQL 2008 R2**
- **Versión XAMPP:** 3.2.4
- **Arquitectura:** x64
- **PHP Extension Build:** API20180731, TS, VC15

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora es descargar el controlador **SQLSRV59** y copiar los archivos a la ubicación C:\xampp\php\ext

- php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
- php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
- php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll

Además de copiar los archivos, modifique **php.ini** con las siguientes expresiónes:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
```

Para verificar que el controlador ha sido instalado, lo revise en la vista de **phpinfo.php** donde obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de revisar y seguir los pasos anteriores, sigo teniendo problemas para conectarme. No sé si necesito un controlador o configuración adicional.

Comment: Se puede ver que instalaste el controlador [`SQLSRV` para `PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) (_no la extensión [`SQLSRV`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.sqlsrv.php)_). Intenta conectarte utilizando el la clase [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: [Aca podes ver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php#install-the-drivers) todo lo que necesitas hacer. Aparentemente es mas o menos lo que ya hiciste. Intenta agregando como extension solo `php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll`, guarda y reinicia Apache. Fijate nuevamente en el `phpinfo.php` si tenes al extensión `sqlsrv` activa.

Comment: @Marcos Es necesario agregar los cuatros archivos `php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll`
`php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll`
`php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll`
`php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll` en la ubicación C:/xampp/php/ext sin tenerlo declarados en el `php.ini`?

Comment: No, por lo que detallas en tu pregunta solo deberías copiar en el directorio y cargar en el `php.ini` solo los `ts`, ya que los `nts` no son compatibles.